# MultiTab editor with ability of adding tabs dynamically

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an eclipse RCP plugin. Now I need to create a multitab editor with the ability of adding tabs dynamically in run time but I don't have any idea how to do it. Does any one know how can I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this similar to `MultiPageEditorPart` - it has several `addPage` functions.  Either use this editor as is, or use it for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

It is too late, But some might get benefit from this code:

```
/** The text editor used in the new page. */
private TextEditor editor;


private StyledText text;
/**
 * Creates a multi-page editor example.
 */
public MultiPageEditor() {
    super();
    ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(this);
}

void createDynamicPage() {
    try {
        editor = new TextEditor();
        int index = addPage(editor, getEditorInput());
        setPageText(index, "new page"+index);
    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        ErrorDialog.openError(
            getSite().getShell(),
            "Error creating nested editor",
            null,
            e.getStatus());
    }
}


void createMainPage() {

    Composite composite = new Composite(getContainer(), SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    composite.setLayout(layout);
    layout.numColumns = 2;

    Button clickButton = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.BEGINNING);
    gd.horizontalSpan = 2;
    clickButton.setLayoutData(gd);
    clickButton.setText("click");

    clickButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
          createDynamicPage();
        }
    });

    int index = addPage(composite);

    setPageText(index, "main page");
}

/**
 * Creates the pages of the multi-page editor.
 */
protected void createPages() {
    createMainPage();
```